# Synonymize tags that end in suffixes with ones that don't (there're exceptions, though)

Tags: feature-request, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

**Most tags ending in suffixes (such as "-ing" or a plural "-s") should be synonymized with the root word tag.**

There's a [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) tag for the topic of clicking your mouse in a UI. There's also a [clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clicking) tag for the action of clicking your mouse in a UI.

Tags with names ending in suffixes should be synonymized because they're basically the same thing.

Currently, without these tags synonymized, searching for [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/click) will return different results than the corresponding [clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clicking) tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So [mining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mining), not the greatest tag in the world as it's used for bitcoin mining and also for data mining would be less confusing if we forced it to be a synonym of [min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/min)?

FWIW I think the [data-mining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-mining) questions in [mining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mining) should be retagged manually.

I can construct other unrelated pairs where one of them is a currrent tag, e.g. [rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rating) or [bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bit) or [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not)

The trouble with general rules such as this is that the exceptions bite you.

If you want to do it manually, there's already a process for that. Just make the suggestions once you have the rep to do so.

Comment: I mean MOST tags ending with ing. Mining and min are different.